# Ruby on Rails devise translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

views/devise/sessions/new.html.haml

```
%h2 
  = t('devise.sessions.link')
```

devise can't find the translation

```
<span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: ru.devise.sessions.link">Link</span>
```

but

```
ru:
  devise:
    sessions:
      link: 'Войти'
```

is present in config/locales/devise.ru.yml

Comment: I'm just find problem, there are incorrect translation file with two entry of sections devise: sessions:

Comment: Why don't you answer the question, then, and explain it so others can benefit?

Comment: I've answered the question, why don't you upvote to reward my effort? :-p

Comment: Thanks Vyacheslav Loginov, but this was directed to Steve Ross. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails merges the parsed yaml files correctly but,
when a key is used twice within the same translation file,
one of them will be replaced by the other,
the same way it would when adding an existing key value pair to a manually created hash.

example yaml file:

```
----
:foo: bar
:foo: foo
```

example code use:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'yaml'
YAML::load("--- \n:foo: :bar\n:foo: :foo\n")
```

output:

```
=> {:foo=>:foo}
```